# MySQL - autofill column for order based on other columns

Tags: mysql, sql, autocomplete, innodb

I am quite inexperienced SQL user. I never really used SQL for things like autofilling a column. It was mostly SELECTS (JOINS etc).

I have one table and I would like to fill values into article_order column for ordering id_article for each id_issue.

I have this example on [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/83c62/1)

```
+------------------------+----------+------------+---------------+
| id_issue_article_issue | id_issue | id_article | article_order |
+------------------------+----------+------------+---------------+
|                      1 |        1 |          1 | NULL          |
|                      2 |        1 |          2 | NULL          |
|                      3 |        2 |          3 | NULL          |
|                      4 |        2 |          4 | NULL          |
|                      5 |        2 |          5 | NULL          |
+------------------------+----------+------------+---------------+
Desired table
+------------------------+----------+------------+---------------+
| id_issue_article_issue | id_issue | id_article | article_order |
+------------------------+----------+------------+---------------+
|                      1 |        1 |          1 |             1 |
|                      2 |        1 |          2 |             2 |
|                      3 |        2 |          3 |             1 |
|                      4 |        2 |          4 |             2 |
|                      5 |        2 |          5 |             3 |
+------------------------+----------+------------+---------------+
```

I was looking for solutions for a bit, I might have missed something, but I still can't figure it out.
Even hints would help. 
Thanks alot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little tricky in MySQL, but you can do it using variables:

```
set @rn := 0;
set @ai := -1;

update t
    set article_order = if(@ai = id_issue, @rn := @rn + 1,
                           if(@ai := id_issue, @rn := 1, @rn := 1
                             )
                          )
    order by id_issue, id_article;
```

Comment: Wow, that was very fast answer and it worked! Thanks!